# getItemByID is not a function

Tags: javascript

I have the following script  that is returning the error message "list.getItemByID is not a function" and I can't figure out why. All examples use this function.
I am trying to iterate through thumbnails on a page and then load the list they are from and get additional information for each thumbnail. Just to test I am trying to just show the titles in an alert at this point.

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getMyList, "SP.js");

function getMyList() {

    var listTitle = 'Faces'
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = ctx.get_web();
    var lists = web.get_lists();
    var list = lists.getByTitle(listTitle);


    var items = [];
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('ms-tileview-tile-detailsBox');

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var title = elements[i].getAttribute("id");
        var id = title.substring(10, GetSubstringIndex(title, "_", 3));
        var item = list.sp.getItem
        items.push(item);
        ctx.load(item, "Title");
    };
    if (items) {
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            var titles = "Titles of the selected items:\n";
            for (var j = 0; j < items.length; j++) {
                titles += items[j].get_item("Title") + "\n";
            }
            alert(titles);
        }, function (sender, args) {
            alert('Request failed. '
                + args.get_message() + '\n'
                + args.get_stackTrace());
        });
    };
};


function GetSubstringIndex(str, substring, n) {
    var times = 0, index = null;

    while (times < n && index !== -1) {
        index = str.indexOf(substring, index + 1);
        times++;
    }

    return index;
};
```

Comment: The above code has the ID of the item requested hard coded just to test. In theory it would look up the thumbnail's id that is calculated but again- jus testing.

Comment: have you tried getItemById ? with a small d in Id?

Comment: As @Gwny stated, the last letter is lower case.  JavaScript is case-sensitive, and as seen in this MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019.aspx), the method is `getItemById()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a capital D on list.getItemByID, it should be list.getItemById

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj246019.aspx